# Text message time issue

Tags: sms, htc-wildfire-s

My text message app is behaving rather oddly:

When receiving a text message from a friend, and instantly replying, so that the time of receiving his or her text message is equal to the time of my reply, my reply is placed above the received text message.

ASCII example ;) :

```
From Theodor 16.23: Dinner sounds good, when do you want to eat?
From Anna 16.23: Do you want to have dinner tonight?
```

The phone is a HTC Wildfire S running Android 2.3.3

Comment: Nice clear and accurate question. +1 for making the effort Theodor.

Comment: I don't think there will be a solution, perhaps short of a replacement SMS app. Obviously the time is only recorded as precise as a minute, and when faced with two equal values is more-or-less choosing at random which to show first. If the data was saved to the second it would be a non-issue. Even a third-party SMS app is probably using the same underlying data, so that probably won't help.

Comment: @AlEverett - Yes that's what I thought at first, but wouldn't it be more likely that the app is comparing the timestamp longs of the text msg, which is in milliseconds (no?), and hence something else is wrong. I was thinking if the system time on the phone is not set right, but slightly off, the time stamp from the received sms might be of a higher value. Does the os use the timestamp from the service provider or system time for received messages by the way?

Answer (score 1):

i believe this is a problem with most stock messaging apps (i have had this problem with several stock sms apps, as i re-ROM a lot ;) ), and i believe the app may be comparing times with the cutoff at minutes, and have a filter that says if they're at the same time (same minute) display the incoming before the outgoing. This is only my guess.

My solution every time has been to use a replacement SMS app (i've never had a third-party SMS app behave badly in this way), and they usually have more functionality anyways. If you would like to try some, i've used [Handcent SMS](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.handcent.nextsms&feature=search_result) for a long time, but recently switched to [GoSMS](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.jb.gosms&hl=en) and love it.

Comment: +1 for "may be comparing times with the cutoff at minutes" - I think this is the key to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

GoSMS Pro for Android works pretty well. You can try this.
AFAIK, the stock messaging app considers the network provided time values. You can try syncronising your phone's time with that of network provided values.